# Script to show independencies and inheritances

Tags: solidity

I have my projects in Solidity with contracts in different files, folders. I would like to write a Python/Javascript script to tell me how the files are dependent on each other (i.e. A requires B, then B requires C and D, etc.). I also want to do it for class inheritance. What is the best way to do it? Do I just have to parse the code as text file and look for import or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a textual (or regular expression) parsing issue which has nothing specific with Ethereum.

Comment: that's true. How can I move it to relevant section?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some existing tools you can use instead to generate a graph of your contracts dependencies

https://github.com/ConsenSys/surya